# Titanium IOS app - unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, webview, titanium, unrecognized-selector

I have an app for Android and IOS. On Android it works ok, but on IOS, I have this error:

```
[ERROR] :  Script Error {
[ERROR] :      backtrace = "#0 () at :0";
[ERROR] :      line = 197;
[ERROR] :      message = "-[TiUIViewProxy fireEvent:withObject:remove:thisObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xeb07400";
[ERROR] :      sourceId = 303988736;
[ERROR] :      sourceURL = "file:///Users/Almudena/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.0/Applications/380C4F68-33F0-4198-BAB4-B53FC5280609/APPNAME.app/views/interconexiones/InterconexionesSaldoGrafico2.js";
[ERROR] :  }
```

It's very strange because, I have views, and InterconexionesSaldoGrafico2 is a module that return a view.

The first time I load InterconexionesSaldoGrafico2 works ok, but the second one, I have the previous error.

In this module I load a web view, and the error point at :

```
var loadWebView = function(e) {
    Ti.App.fireEvent('InitWebviewHTML5Step', {
        values : dataInterconexionesJson,
        dp : utils.getFactorTodp() //HERE
    });
};
```

I call this method:

```
webviewHTML5StepPortrait.addEventListener('load', loadWebView);
```

Do you know what could be the error?

Thank you very much

**UPDATE**

Sometimes exception happens and sometimes the app is closed without saying anything.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what

> utils.getFactorTodp

does, but if you want to pass the function and not evaluate it, you must remove the parenthesis. So if `dp` is called later by the eventListener, replace `utils.getFactorTodp()` by `utils.getFactorTodp`

That way, you will reference to the function instead of trying to evaluate it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. utils.getFactorTodp() is a function that returns a value. I use the value (not the function) inside webview, so I think with the parenthesis it is correct, doesn't it?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you replace the function by a constant value or by the value that your function returns directly?